# Why my autoencoder outputs have low variance?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to create a convolutional autoencoder which recover (800,800,1) images. What i found is that if I use a deeper architecture (more than 2 layers for encoder and decoder) the outputs tend to have a small variance and a lower mean value, but I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It could be ELBO loss fault, try to use [MMD](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02262) instead